# C# Button Object as a parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a function with a parameter so whenever I call it, it will change the button's back color but my code doesn't work, any ideas

```
Button button = new Button();
        private void Change(object sender)
        {
            if (button.Visible == true)
            {
                button.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        private void hr1_left2_btn_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Change(hr1_left2_btn);
           
        }
```

Comment: Type `sender` as `Button`.

Comment: change the button inside of your function to sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps like this? I've changed the Sender Arg type of the Change function to ref a button object.

```cs
        private void Change(Button sender) {
            if (sender.Visible)
                sender.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void hr1_left2_btn_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Change(hr1_left2_btn);
        }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not a good idea. Please explain what you changed and why, and *then* show the code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen done

Comment: `== true`, really?

Comment: @StevenJohnSunga please mark my answer as the correct answer, thanks.